# when page reload how can i call the latest value in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    s => s.DergiID, (SelectList)ViewBag.dergis, " -Seçiniz- ", new { 
    @class = "form-control check", required = (string)null 
})
```

I want to automatically select the last option when the page reload
How can I do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector to make last option selected. [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) will selects the last matched element.

```
$(function() {
    $("select#DergiID option:last").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

Comment: What id do you get on your dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form action="Create" method="post" class="steps-validation wizard-circle">
  @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.id)
  <div class="row">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.DergiID, (SelectList)ViewBag.dergis, " -Seçiniz- ", new { @class = "form-control check", required = (string)null 
   })
  </div>

 <script>
  $(function() {
        $("select#DergiID option:last").attr("selected", "selected");
  });
 </script>
```

it oke solved but I need to run it depending on id. because edit and create page using same page . so edit problem this. I need to run it according to id id is only works if it is null